# Question about limits with variable on exponent

Tags: limits

So I have to find the following limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^{1/n}.$$I said that this is $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^n\right]^{1/n^2}=\left(e^2\right)^{\lim_{n\to\infty}1/n^2}=1.$$Now I know that the final answer is correct, but my method seems to me to be wrong. Can I seperate a limit in the way I  did - i.e. is my working correct? Is there any other more elegant way to find the limit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your procedure has no defect at all.

Comment: I'm tempted to use the replacement $h=\frac1n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need to go through this all:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 1+\frac{2}{n}=1$$ and 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$$
therefore 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^{1/n}=1^0=1$$